# JAWS reads hidden content on page refresh with IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have a form. After submitting it, the form is hidden with `display:none` and in her place appears a confirmation message (which changes style from `display:none` to `display:block`). There is no AJAX call and no reloading of the page. The confirmation just changes display property.

JAWS does not read the text of the confirmation, even when I put `aria-live="assertive"` on its container. I made JAWS read it by putting focus on the confirmation message container. But the problem is that when I reload the page, JAWS reads the confirmation message again, even though on page load it has `display:none` and `aria-hidden="true"`.

I tried everything I found on Stack Overflow: I tested `aria-busy`, `speak:none`, both types of `aria-live`, hiding message with `aria-hidden`, and nothing works. JAWS still reads the confirmation message on refreshing the page.

I cannot paste the code due to the nature of the project, but I hope my description of the problem is understandable.

**UPDATE:**

Based on @Josh suggestions I updated the code - now I insert the error/confirmation div to the live region using JavaScript. But the problem still persists.

Here is the code structure:
[image]

I append either `confirmation-status-publish` or `error-status-publish` to the respective wrapper above with all the `aria`.

Comment: Is that confirm message is created using JavaScript or you just use HTML or any other frontend framework? It can better if you post a simple sample because we can miss some vital information when we try to make a test based on description.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see what's happening with your code, I suspect that you may not be using the aria live region correctly.

For a live region to work, it has to be present on page load, as an element with an `aria-live` or equivalent `role` attribute. A live region cannot be added after page load via scripting, because it won't work.

Any content that is in the aria live element when the page loads will just be treated as part of the page and not announced in any special way.

Announcements from the live region are **only made** when content is dynamically added to the live region through JavaScript. The `aria-live="polite/assertive"` and `aria-atomic="true/false"` attributes will control the behavior of how it functions.

So, for this to work, you'd need to do something like:

On page load:

```
<div aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <form>
       ... some code
    </form>
<div>
```

After form Submission:

```
<div aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div id="confirmation">
       ... some other code
    </div>
<div>
```

I'd encourage you to take a look at the source code on the [Terrill Thompson Aria Live Region Test Page](https://terrillthompson.com/tests/aria/live-scores.html) and run some tests using JAWS/IE to get a feel for how it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. Based on them I changed the code, and now I insert a `div` with confirmation/error using JavaSript. Jaws reads the region correctly now once the confirmation/error appears. But when I refresh the page, it still reads it, as if it was still visible. I updated the question with printscreen.

Comment: I also tested with initial `aria-live=off`, which switches to `aria-live="polite"` on error/confirmation message appearance. It reads the message fine, but still it reads it again when refreshing the page though the message is already gone.

Comment: I also made experiments without `aria` at all - JAWS reads the part of the page which is getting hidden with `display:none`. JAWS seems to somehow remember the previous look of the page, and repeats it on the page load, which renders completely new content. But because of still remembering the old content, it reads what is getting hidden and not what is being shown. I am completely lost.

Comment: I suggest you to do not post the picture of the code and try to provide a sample which we can try to run on IE 11 to reproduce the issue with JAWS.